# copy files from local machine to ftp server c

Tags: c#, ftp

I need to copy some txt files to ftp server from local machine. I used following code. (took from : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.xxxx.com/");

    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "paswword");

    // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
    StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(@"E:\log.txt");
    byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
    sourceStream.Close();
    request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

    response.Close();
    }
```

but i cause "The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command" error. How could I solve that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing file name at URI. For example:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.xxxx.com/log.txt");
```

Take a good look at example you using. Note **test.htm**?

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
```